# Text Overflow Ellipsis with Table

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that gets centered using class box-center. Now I want to add text-overflow ellipsis but it doesn't center anymore.

```
.box-center {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .ellipsed {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;

    span {
      display: table-cell;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding this as well but this doesn't text-overflow ellipsis.

```
.ellipsed {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;

  span {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box-center">
  <div class="ellipsed">
    <span>Some text to be ellipsed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use `text-overlfow:ellipsis` you need to define width of the element as you need to tell the element after what width it should hide and show ellipsis.

See this dummy example based on simple css. I have added just a dummy width and its working

```css
.ellipsed {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-center">
  <div class="ellipsed">
    <span>Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed Some text to be ellipsed </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep width at 100%? It's part of a layout and actually box-center expands until the content width. I'm not trying to make text ellipsed with fixed width but rather do it when the viewport is smaller than the text in span.

Comment: you can add 100% width also it will be 100% of its parent div i have just given an example because in your current situation 100% width is more than the content width so effect will not show but if the content is wide enough than width 100% will also work....check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

your html is wrong

you use of `className` but use to `class`

```
<div class="box-center">
  <div class="ellipsed">
    <span>Some text to be ellipsed</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, should have changed it. It's jsx so className is correct.